# Multiple ARSCNViews and displaying only face mesh in ARKit Face Tracking

Tags: xcode, arkit, face

Following Apple's ARKit code example, I was able to display Face Mesh on the real face. Now I want to display the face mesh only in a separate ARSCNview, i.e. one view showing the real face and the second view to display the face mesh only (so later I can modify it, e.g. to make an avatar). How to do it?

It is said that it is possible to run to ARSCN views at the same time, e.g. see,
[Is it possible to run two ARSCNView at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691179/is-it-possible-to-run-two-arscnview-at-the-same-time)

But I was not able to run make the second scene where only the face mesh is display to show up. Here are my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else { fatalError() }
    sceneView.delegate = self


    sceneView.isPlaying = true // this is my first scene view
    transformView.isPlaying = true // second scene view


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()

    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    sceneView.session.pause()
}

extension FaceTrackViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor,
        //          let device = sceneView.MTLDevice else { return nil }
        let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else { return nil }
    let faceGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device)
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: faceGeometry)
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .lines

    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.transparency = 0.5

    return node



}



func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor, let faceGeometry = node.geometry as? ARSCNFaceGeometry else { return }

    faceGeometry.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)

}
```

Only the first scene view with face mesh overlapped on my real face is displayed