# Can I make AR work with Google Cardboard and ARCore/ARKit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore, google-cardboard

My goal is to have my image-tracking AR app useable with a headset. My friends and I play a game on our game nights that could really be advanced with AR - problem is, our hands need to be free, so using AR with a headset (something affordable for us all - like Google Cardboard) is needed.

I've looked around and found older videos covering Vuforia, but I've seen in this post that support was deprecated: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity/vuforia-google-cardboard

Vuforia is very expensive for just simple game-night fun... so I'd rather use ARCore and ARKit, if possible.

Is implementation for this even possible today with Unity + Cardboard + ARCore? (If I need to cut a hole in the cardboard for my camera, that's no problem)

Comment: You can simply develop based on AR workflow, but set the customised stereo cam for rendering on Canvas.

Comment: Hi @BrettComardelle, ARKit allows implement you stereo vision for cardboards. Look at my answer – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691179/is-it-possible-to-run-two-arscnview-at-the-same-time/53692637#53692637 . Don't know whether it's still possible in Unity...